# I'm trying to convert float to str in python ctypes but it never hapenning

Tags: python, c, ctypes, square, square-root

I'm making a simple calculator and i need to do some square root function and when i start that it comes wrong. These are my codes.

test.dll

```c
#include <stdio.h>

float negative_check(float num)
{
    if(num < 0){
        num = -num;
    }
    return num;
}

float calc_sqrt(int calcFirst)
{
    const float difference = 0.00001;
    float calcResult = 1.0;

    while(negative_check(calcResult * calcResult - calcFirst) >= difference){
        calcResult = (calcFirst/calcResult + calcResult)/2.0;
    }
    
    return calcResult;
}
```

python

```py
from ctypes import *
simple_calc = CDLL("test.dll")
result_var = simple_calc.calc_sqrt(4)
print("Result: ", result_var)
```

bash

```sh
Output: 4502151
```

But it gaves me some memory adresses. What should i do?

Comment: Have you tried telling ctypes what type of object is returned from the function?

Comment: Read about `.argtypes` and `.restype` attributes in the documentation.

Comment: Nope these documentation not helped.